# Mock external call in all unit test

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking

I need some help to mock a function which is getting an external call.

My function send_slack_message is in a module called slack_utils.

This is the structure of my project (which is a django project)

```
<my_project>
         |
         - helpers
         |           |
         |           - _init_.py
         |           - slack_utils.py
         |                             |
         |                             -  def send_slack_message(.....):
         |
         - tests
                 - _init_.py
                  - test_slack_message.py
```

I would like to mock send_slack_message in *init* module of the tests package do not take care anymore of external calls in all tests I am going to write in my test_*.py modules.

Any helps of good idea to achieve my goal would be really appreciated.

Thanks.
Walter

Comment: What test frame work are you using?  Are you using unit-test?  If so, would [`setUpModule` and `tearDownModule`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#setupmodule-and-teardownmodule) be useful, or do you want something more global than that?

Comment: Hello Rushy,
yes, sorry you're right I didn't specify too much.
By the way I am working with python 2.7, unittest and mock.

I did something more generic. Check my answer....